# Объясните пожалуйста этот кусочек кода. Написан на C

Tags: c, define

```
#define CALL(x) if(counter++ && !(x))error(#x,__LINE__,counter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макрос - это просто подстановка. Не более и не менее. Отрабатывает она до компиляции. Если компилятор где то встретит `CALL(1)`, то он заменит это на `if(counter++ && !(1))error("1",17,counter)`. А будет ли это правильно и валидно - уже решит компилятор.

В этой подстановке можно заметить несколько особенностей. Во первых, x взят в скобки - это для того, что бы если x - выражение, то что бы не все осталось корректно. Во вторых - это выражение `#x` - он заменятся на строковое представление - то есть просто само выражение в кавычках. И третье - это специальная "переменная" `__LINE__`, которая заменяется на номер текущей строки.

Что же получается по факту. Если `counter > 0` и выражение `x` ложно (равно нулю), то вызывается функция `error`, которой передается три аргумента - само выражение-условие в виде строки, номер строки в файле и счетчик.

Comment: Наверное имелось в виду `counter != 0` перед `if  (counter++ ...)` ?

Comment: не знаю. не могу сопоставить с моим текстом.

Comment: Вот этот текст:  *`"Что же получается по факту. Если counter > 0 и..."`*